# Get the fixture that was clicked on

Tags: libgdx, box2d

There are several physical bodies of different shapes on the screen. I want to click on the screen to get a physical body(if of course the click fell on it). I have no problems with converting the coordinates from the screen to the world and checking whether I hit the round collider(I just go through the list of "circles" and check the distance from the "click" to its center, if it is more than the radius, then skip). But I'm having problems with other shapes. I can't use raycast, as it doesn't detect the fixture inside which its starting point is. It seems to me that I'm missing some built-in solution that I didn't notice in the documentation. Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. World.QueryAABB
[documentation pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EthoM.png)